# Is there an easy way to change pop up windows to modals (with minimal changes to JS code)

Tags: javascript, css, html

I've seen several examples on SO of using modals rather than pop up windows and I'm trying to update some old JS code to do this without having to rewrite everything (as I'm very new to JS and don't understand a 99% of it yet).

The code we are using at the moment is included below. We're basically trying to get a christmas calender up and running for a local charity, so want the calender 'windows' to only open after specific dates and not before. Each 'window' has it's own html page with an image, a puzzle and clue, then a link to the charity (I've included one as an example, as all 24 are different). The calender is working great at the moment by using pop up windows. But we want to update the code to use modals (or something like that) instead, as having the window header/url bar looks clunky.

I suggested switching to modals as they look a lot 'cleaner' than windows, but if anyone has any better alternatives then I'd be happy to hear them.

Code for the main part of the calender:

```
<body>
<script>

    function dooropen(door)
    {
    today=new Date();
    daynow=today.getDate();
    monthnow=today.getMonth();

if (monthnow!=11 && monthnow!=0) {alert("This calender unlocks in December. Please come back then."); return false;}
if (daynow==door-1) {alert("Come back tomorrow to see what's behind the door!");return false;}
if (door>daynow) {alert("You\'ll have to wait "+(door-daynow)+" days before this door will unlock!"); return false;}

oNewWindow=window.open(urlsarray[door], '_blank','directories=no,height='+heightarray[door]+',width='+widtharray[door]+',location=0,menubar=0,resizable=yes,scrollbars='+scrollbarsarray[door]+',status=no,titlebar=0,toolbar=0');
    }

    urlsarray = new Array();
    widtharray = new Array();
    heightarray = new Array();
    scrollbarsarray= new Array();

    var x=285; 
    var y=50; 
    var rows=6; 
    var cols=4; 
    var spacinghoriz=120; 
    var spacingvert=100; 

    urlsarray[1]="1.html"; widtharray[1]="420"; heightarray[1]="550";
    urlsarray[2]="2.html"; widtharray[2]="420"; heightarray[2]="550";
    urlsarray[3]="3.html"; widtharray[3]="420"; heightarray[3]="550";
    urlsarray[4]="4.html"; widtharray[4]="420"; heightarray[4]="550";
    urlsarray[5]="5.html"; widtharray[5]="420"; heightarray[5]="550";
    urlsarray[6]="6.html"; widtharray[6]="420"; heightarray[6]="550";
    urlsarray[7]="7.html"; widtharray[7]="420"; heightarray[7]="550";
    urlsarray[8]="8.html"; widtharray[8]="420"; heightarray[8]="550";
    urlsarray[9]="9.html"; widtharray[9]="420"; heightarray[9]="550";
    urlsarray[10]="10.html"; widtharray[10]="420"; heightarray[10]="550";
    urlsarray[11]="11.html"; widtharray[11]="420"; heightarray[11]="550";
    urlsarray[12]="12.html"; widtharray[12]="420"; heightarray[12]="550";
    urlsarray[13]="13.html"; widtharray[13]="420"; heightarray[13]="550";
    urlsarray[14]="14.html"; widtharray[14]="420"; heightarray[14]="550";
    urlsarray[15]="15.html"; widtharray[15]="420"; heightarray[15]="550";
    urlsarray[16]="16.html"; widtharray[16]="420"; heightarray[16]="550";
    urlsarray[17]="17.html"; widtharray[17]="420"; heightarray[17]="550";
    urlsarray[18]="18.html"; widtharray[18]="420"; heightarray[18]="550";
    urlsarray[19]="19.html"; widtharray[19]="420"; heightarray[19]="550";
    urlsarray[20]="20.html"; widtharray[20]="420"; heightarray[20]="550";
    urlsarray[21]="21.html"; widtharray[21]="420"; heightarray[21]="550";
    urlsarray[22]="22.html"; widtharray[22]="420"; heightarray[22]="550";
    urlsarray[23]="23.html"; widtharray[23]="420"; heightarray[23]="550";
    urlsarray[24]="24.html"; widtharray[24]="420"; heightarray[24]="550";

    var doorno=1;
    for (h=0;h<rows;++h)
    {
    for(g=0; g<cols; ++g, ++doorno)
    {
    document.write('<a class="button" onClick="dooropen('+doorno+');" href="#" style="position: absolute; left:'+(x+(g*spacinghoriz))+'px; top:'+(y+(h*spacingvert))+'px;">'+doorno+'</a>');}
    }

</script>
</body>
```

Code for the main page, where the iframe will appear:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Christmas Calender</title>
    <link rel="shorcut icon" href="favicon.jpg" type="image/jpg">
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.jpg" type="image/x-icon">
</head>

<body style="background-color:#000000">

<center>
<iframe src="calendarcode.html" title="Christmas Calendar 2018" width=980 height=650 frameborder=0>
</iframe>
</center>

<!-- Button to return to previous room -->
<center>
    <p><a href="room1.html"><img src="arrowleft.png" alt="Room1" width=97 height=97 border=0></a>
</center>

<!-- Logo -->
<center>
    <a href=""><img src="logo.png" alt="charity name" width=40 height=40 border=0></a>
</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Code for example pop up window:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Puzzle 1</title>
</head>

<body background-color="#000000">

<center>
<img src="images/puzzle1.gif" alt="Puzzle1" width=155 height=189 border=0>

<p>Clue text...</p>

<p>_ _ _ _ _</p>

<p><a href=""><img src="logo.png" alt="Logo" width=33 height=33 border=0></a></p>

</center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Is it just the `alerts` that you are looking to change (to modals)?

Comment: And the individual pop ups for each day of the calender (in the array).

Comment: It seems like those are also done with `alert`s at the moment?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. Yep, all the alerts create pop up windows. We're trying to change those to modal boxes (or something similar) instead. Or perhaps there is a way to just hide the top of a browser window (the title bar, url bar, buttons, etc) in javascript like you can do with scroll bars?

Comment: It'd be good to know a bit more about what you mean by popup windows... are they just text, or do they have something more?

Comment: They are similar to the example I added (the third bit of code), with a black background, some images or gifs, a bit of text and a logo that links to the charity. I assume if we use modals instead of windows, then we'll need to add a close button as well.

Comment: The code does two separate things which, could, in theory be grouped into a single function, though it's likely to require fairly significant additions to the code. Currently the code uses `alert` to display certain warnings, and `window.open` to show the additional content

Comment: Ah. The problem with that is that we would struggle to rewrite the original code ourselves. Definitely not in the few days we have to get this up and running. Is there a way to do it keeping the original code as similar as possible (even if it isn't the most streamlined way of doing things)?

Comment: I presume that hiring someone isn't an option?

Comment: They don't have funds for that. They had another guy who volunteered to help out (who had more experience with JS things), but he's been ill and we just offered to have a look and see if we could do anything with it. If it isn't possible to do then we'll just keep the pop ups as windows as they at least work correctly, and we know how to remove scrollbars to make them look a bit cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend that you use a library here if you don't want to edit the code too heavily. I can't say that this is particularly good code, but I've tried to edit it as little as possible.

Here a new function, `openModal` is being called instead of alert. You could replace the default `window.alert` function but I think that'd complicate matters further.

This uses the [tingle](https://robinparisi.github.io/tingle/) library for creating modals in javascript.

```js
function createModal() {
  return new tingle.modal({
    footer: false,
    stickyFooter: false,
    closeMethods: ['overlay', 'button', 'escape'],
    closeLabel: "Close",
    cssClass: ['custom-class-1', 'custom-class-2'],
  });
}

function createUrlModal(url) {
  var newModal = createModal();

  newModal.setContent('<iframe src="' + url + '"></iframe>');
  
  return newModal;
}


function createTextModal(text) {
  var newModal = createModal();

  newModal.setContent('<h1>' + text + '</h1>');
 
  
  return newModal;
}

function openModal(textOrUrl) {
  var modalToOpen = textOrUrl.indexOf('html') > -1 || textOrUrl.indexOf('.com') > -1 ?
    createUrlModal(textOrUrl) :
    createTextModal(textOrUrl);
    
  modalToOpen.open();
}

function dooropen(door) {
  today = new Date();
  daynow = today.getDate();
  monthnow = today.getMonth();

  if (monthnow != 11 && monthnow != 0) {
    openModal("This calender unlocks in December. Please come back then.");
    return false;
  }
  if (daynow == door - 1) {
    openModal("Come back tomorrow to see what's behind the door!");
    return false;
  }
  if (door > daynow) {
    openModal("You\'ll have to wait " + (door - daynow) + " days before this door will unlock!");
    return false;
  }

  oNewWindow = openModal(urlsarray[door]);
}

urlsarray = new Array();
widtharray = new Array();
heightarray = new Array();
scrollbarsarray = new Array();

var x = 285;
var y = 50;
var rows = 6;
var cols = 4;
var spacinghoriz = 120;
var spacingvert = 100;

urlsarray[1] = "https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page";
widtharray[1] = "420";
heightarray[1] = "550";
urlsarray[2] = "2.html";
widtharray[2] = "420";
heightarray[2] = "550";
urlsarray[3] = "3.html";
widtharray[3] = "420";
heightarray[3] = "550";
urlsarray[4] = "4.html";
widtharray[4] = "420";
heightarray[4] = "550";
urlsarray[5] = "5.html";
widtharray[5] = "420";
heightarray[5] = "550";
urlsarray[6] = "6.html";
widtharray[6] = "420";
heightarray[6] = "550";
urlsarray[7] = "7.html";
widtharray[7] = "420";
heightarray[7] = "550";
urlsarray[8] = "8.html";
widtharray[8] = "420";
heightarray[8] = "550";
urlsarray[9] = "9.html";
widtharray[9] = "420";
heightarray[9] = "550";
urlsarray[10] = "10.html";
widtharray[10] = "420";
heightarray[10] = "550";
urlsarray[11] = "11.html";
widtharray[11] = "420";
heightarray[11] = "550";
urlsarray[12] = "12.html";
widtharray[12] = "420";
heightarray[12] = "550";
urlsarray[13] = "13.html";
widtharray[13] = "420";
heightarray[13] = "550";
urlsarray[14] = "14.html";
widtharray[14] = "420";
heightarray[14] = "550";
urlsarray[15] = "15.html";
widtharray[15] = "420";
heightarray[15] = "550";
urlsarray[16] = "16.html";
widtharray[16] = "420";
heightarray[16] = "550";
urlsarray[17] = "17.html";
widtharray[17] = "420";
heightarray[17] = "550";
urlsarray[18] = "18.html";
widtharray[18] = "420";
heightarray[18] = "550";
urlsarray[19] = "19.html";
widtharray[19] = "420";
heightarray[19] = "550";
urlsarray[20] = "20.html";
widtharray[20] = "420";
heightarray[20] = "550";
urlsarray[21] = "21.html";
widtharray[21] = "420";
heightarray[21] = "550";
urlsarray[22] = "22.html";
widtharray[22] = "420";
heightarray[22] = "550";
urlsarray[23] = "23.html";
widtharray[23] = "420";
heightarray[23] = "550";
urlsarray[24] = "24.html";
widtharray[24] = "420";
heightarray[24] = "550";

var doorno = 1;
for (h = 0; h < rows; ++h) {
  for (g = 0; g < cols; ++g, ++doorno) {
    document.write('<a class="button" onClick="dooropen(' + doorno + ');" href="#" style="position: absolute; left:' + (x + (g * spacinghoriz)) + 'px; top:' + (y + (h * spacingvert)) + 'px;">' + doorno + '</a>');
  }
}
```

```css
.tingle-modal-box__content {
  padding: 0!important;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
}

/* You can use the styles of the modal to adjust its size: */
.tingle-modal-box {
  height: 500px;
  width: 90%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tingle/0.13.2/tingle.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/tingle/0.13.2/tingle.js"></script>
```

Comment: This is amazing! I've 'sort of' got this working. Just trying to work out how to update the attributes/content of the modal windows so they look how the pop up windows on the original code looked. 

I've had a look at the tingle.js page and found the css to change the style of the contents. But can't work out how to change the size/shape of the modal box itself. Right now they are all the same size and not displaying things correctly.

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/7h89j0rpnza06r6/AADldLrOSiPi7oeddA00SMBSa?dl=0

Comment: I'm glad that's working; I've updated the answer to show how you might go about adjusting the size of the modal using css.

Comment: I tried the above already, but it doesn't seem to change the height. I've been playing around with different .css settings but it's as if the modal box is fixed to a specific shape. : (

Comment: I've marked your main answer as correct, as technically you solved my main issue (thank you!). If I can't get the modal windows to resize then I'll write another seperate question about the .css, as I guess that's another specific issue. I appreciate your help though! : )

Comment: @Sudoku I'm glad that helped; it probably is best to discuss the height issues as a separate question, as you'll likely get better help that way. For what it's worth, I've had problems styling the height of modals before, and I've yet to find a very good solution to the problem

Comment: I somehow managed to get it working (ish)! CSS code I've used is: '.tingle_modal-box * { width: 500px; height: 100%; }', then 'iframe { width: 100%; height: 450px; }', and '.tingle-modal-box__content { padding: 0!important; }' . I have no idea why this specific combination worked and all the others didn't, but I'm not going to worry about that for now! One (hopefully) last thing about the code you added above... why is it showing an A~ instead of Close or X for the exit button? I can see the bit of code that sets that to 'Close', but it isn't working for some reason.

Comment: Edit: Ignore the above. I've worked out how to just remove the button entirely! Woohoo! : D

Comment: @Sudoku awesome, great news!